# Python sharedmem in-place copy

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have a large `numpy` array, which I would like to convert to a `sharedmem` array. Now I do it like this:

```
import numpy, sharedmem
array = numpy.zeros(1000000000, dtype = 'f8')
shared_array = sharedmem.empty(1000000000, dtype = 'f8')
shared_array[: ] = array[: ]
del array
```

However, with this approach I have to at particular point maintain in memory both arrays, what creates a problem, as sometimes array is larger than 50% of all memory.

Therefore, the question: is there a method of in-place array conversion?

Comment: It's not possible. Memory allocated for `array` cannot be transformed to an anonymous mmap.

Comment: One way to avoid serializing your big shared array is to write it to the filesystem, then open it as a memory-mapped array (`np.memmap`) from inside your child process. [`joblib` can do this for you automatically](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html#working-with-numerical-data-in-shared-memory-memmaping).